# Having problems with date and time editing

Tags: c#, datetime

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s",
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

     TimeChangedHandler(myDate);
}
```

If I delete 1 number from hours then it works fine, but if I delete both numbers e.x. I want to change from 11 to 22 then it crashes. So how do I make the form `"yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s"` work for all cases? Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `textBox1.Text` exactly?

Comment: `2015-07-20 15:19:42` but I need to make it flexible.

Comment: try yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: @MiķelisGulbis What do you mean by _make it flexible_ exactly? What are the all possible inputs that you try to parse? Please be more specific about your problem. It is not clear what you asking right now.

Comment: we want to change the date and the time

Comment: To handle *only* the format in your question you should use `TryParseExact` and then decide what you should do if the method returns `false` (ie. it cannot be parsed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to indicate that the date/time is invalid, use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to *check* whether or not it's valid, without throwing an exception. Use the return value (true/false) to determine the validity.

Basically, you shouldn't expect that the value is always valid while the user is editing - just like while I'm editing code, it won't always be syntactically correct.

You need to check that it's valid when you actually *use* the value - and until then, probably just add a visual marker to indicate that it's invalid.

You may want to think about whether your `TimeChangedHandler` (whatever that is) should implicitly fire whenever the date/time provided is valid, or whether your UI should provide a more explicit "use this value" action (e.g. a button).

Also, consider using a `DateTimePicker` as a friendlier way of selecting a date and time.

Finally, I'd personally avoid using a pattern of `H:m:s`... the date part looks like ISO-8601-like, so I'd suggest using `HH:mm:ss` for complete validity - it would be odd (IMO) to see a value of `2015-07-27 7:55:5` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from using DateTime.TryParse method to check what of two formats your date is :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTime myDate = default(DateTime);
     if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s",
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myDate))
       DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out myDate)     

     if(myDate == default(DateTime)) return; // or
      // throw new ArgumentException("your text here");

     TimeChangedHandler(myDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't expect that the value is always valid while the user is editing - just like while I'm editing code, it won't always be syntactically correct.

this code need to be placed inside try catch as you want flexible values something like this

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          try
          {
     DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     TimeChangedHandler(myDate);
          }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {}
}
```

so, it will not explode if user enters incorrect values and consider using a DateTimePicker as a friendlier way of selecting a date and time.

Answer (score -1):

Since it is on `TextChanged` event handler, you may wanna try to add, a `try...catch` handling during real time edits.

```
try
{
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    TimeChangedHandler(myDate);
}catch( Exception ex )
{
    //Catch exception
}
```

Although a better solution would be placing it on a different event. Does the flexible edit means real time editing? If it is, changing the text from 11 to 22 during that time may cause the format to change, so the `ParseExact` would be better be placed on different event.

Comment: I don't know why they down-voted you, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: It's okay but you can also try `DateTime.TryParseExact` as @Jon Skeet mentioned, to avoid throwing of exception. (If you want to avoid `try... catch`)

Comment: I downvoted because there is a `TryParseExact` method that is the solution to this problem. Calling the non-try version of the method and then catching the exception is an antipattern.